# Remove the extra space in a link text after break the word

Tags: css, material-ui, typography

I'm working on a navigation, but in large screen the navigation looks like this, but in laptop view the word is breaking.
and it's ok to break the word.

but I want to remove the extra space in the text after.

In the large screen

[image: Large screen]

and another image in laptop view, where i want to remove the space before the border.

[image]

ex: between the "App Service Performance" and "App Explorer" middle gap.

here is my code:

```
<Box
    display="flex"
    justifySelf="start"
    flex="1 1 0"
    alignItems="center"
    sx={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        width: "100%",
        alignItems: "center",
    }}
>
    {pages &&
        pages.map((page: Page, index: number) => (
            <Fragment key={page.id}>
                {index !== 0 && (
                    <Divider
                        sx={{ marginX: 1, paddingY: "15px" }}
                        orientation="vertical"
                        variant="middle"
                        flexItem
                    />
                )}
                <Typography
                    component={Link}
                    to={`/${siteId}/${page.id}`}
                    key={page.id}
                    sx={{
                        color:
                            page.id === activePage?.id
                                ? theme.palette.common.white
                                : theme.palette.grey["200"],

                        textDecoration: "none",
                    }}
                >
                    {page.name}
                </Typography>
            </Fragment>
        ))}
</Box>
```

Comment: Please provide codesandbox with css files.

Comment: here is this. [https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-ioana-kypfdo](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-ioana-kypfdo?file=/src/App.js) if you change the window size you will see the text is break in two line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **whitSpace: "nowrap"** -> For every link like this:

```
<Box
  display="flex"
  justifySelf="start"
  flex="1 1 0"
  alignItems="center"
  sx={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center"
  }}
>
  {pages &&
    pages.map((page, index) => (
      <Fragment key={page.id}>
        {index !== 0 && (
          <Divider
            sx={{ marginX: 1, paddingY: "15px" }}
            orientation="vertical"
            variant="middle"
            flexItem
          />
        )}
        <Typography
          component={Link}
          href={`/`}
          key={page.id}
          sx={{
            color: "#fff",
            textDecoration: "none",
            whiteSpace: "nowrap"
          }}
        >
          {page.name}
        </Typography>
      </Fragment>
    ))}
</Box>
```

And Also add **overflow-x: scroll** in your most parent header class for small scrrens it will work.

Hope, it will work. Thanks.

Comment: if I use the `whiteSpace: "nowrap" ` then it will be take all the width, which is not acceptable, I need to reduce the size only when the window size is small and the navbar text is take two lines.

Comment: So, You can use small size media query and use it that property on that.

Comment: the problem is the pages comes from the api, which is dynamic. and it's a css issue I think, cause the anchor attribute take the full width for the first time of this content length, but when we change the window size or load in a laptop view window it break the anchor text to two line but do not reduce the width.

Comment: Right, But we have window width in our control i think?